# Google Sheets Sortable Arrow

Tags: sorting, validation, google-sheets, filter, spreadsheet

In Google Drive, I converted an Excel Spreadsheet into a Google Sheet. One of the few things that didn't convert across were these sorting arrows. I apologize for not knowing the exact terminology for these, but they are inverted triangles (like arrows) that allow you to quickly access how you want sorting to be done for the entire table via the values of a column range.

[image]

The blue arrows point to the clickable inverted triangles, and the red arrow points to what it looks like when the inverted triangle is clicked.

How do I get this same (or at least similar) effect in Google Sheets for each column? I understand that I can sort by column in Google Sheets, but I have to select the range, and do all the steps correctly each time instead of clicking on the column and clicking once more for sorting the table by its values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

advanced/complex ones can be recreated here:

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

---

but basic ones are accessible by hovering over the right column corner:

[image: 0]